# Dynamically Create Django URL Slug in Function Based View

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have been banging my head against the wall for hours on this and its probably incredibly simple.

I need to generate two url slugs from one model.  One is actually called slug and is a SlugField which is for the Product title, and the other is a category which is a ForeignKey.

Ideally what I would like to have is

```
url(r'^products/(?P<category>[^\.]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', tool_detail, name='tool_detail'),
```

But, the category part of the URL keeps giving generating an "invalid literal for int(), with base 10: 'category' - well, this is one of the errors, I tried many different combinations.

**Model**

```
...
slug = models.SlugField()
category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
...
```

**View**

```
def tool_detail(request, slug):
    tool = get_object_or_404(Tool, slug=slug)
    part = get_object_or_404(Part)
    return render(request, 'tool_detail.html', {'tool': tool, 'part': part})
```

**Template**

```
<a href="{% url 'tool_detail' t.category slug=t.slug %}" ... </a>
```

**URL**

```
url(r'^products/tools/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', tool_detail, name='tool_detail'),
```

Ugh...see how /tools/ is hardcoded?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**URL**

```
# query by primary key.
url(r'^products/(?P<category>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', tool_detail, name='tool_detail'),

# query by the name.
url(r'^products/(?P<category>[\w]+)/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', tool_detail, name='tool_detail'),
```

**View**

```
def tool_detail(request, **kwargs):
    tool = get_object_or_404(Tool, slug=kwargs.get('slug'))
    part = get_object_or_404(Part)
    return render(request, 'tool_detail.html', {'tool': tool, 'part': part})
```

Should work it isn't tested.

Comment: Query by name worked for me! Thank you.  I added `category=t.category` to my url path.

Answer (score 1):

In url only pass on parameter slug, but on url tag you pass two paramter. Only modify like as
Templates

```
  <a href="{% url 'tool_detail' t.slug %}" ... </a>
```

If slug is int we can change url

```
    url(r'^products/tools/(?P<slug>[0-9]+)/$', tool_detail, name='tool_detail'),
```

Some example about how to pass dynamic parameter on url tag
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial04/